# WSO2 EMM features supported

Tags: wso2, saas, wso2-iot

On WSO2 EMM, are following features supported?

- SaaS cloud
- Per App VPN. Security of Data on move
- MS ActiveSync
- PKI Infrastructure / Certs. (SCEP)

As per the online guide, I could not find the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please find the answers inline.

```
SaaS cloud
```

WSO2 EMM will be re-branded as WSO2 Mobile Device Management (MDM) with version 2.0. With the release of 2.0 we have some future plans to integrate this with WSO2 device cloud.

```
Per App VPN. Security of Data on move
```

These are some of the iOS features in new releases. We will support this in a future releases of WSO2 MDM.

```
MS ActiveSync
```

No plans yet for this.

```
PKI Infrastructure / Certs. (SCEP)
```

We do have this right now in EMM as well. It has some inbuilt SCEP components facilitated with inbuilt CA server component.